# SIGSEGV error in spoj program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

[This](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MONKK/) is a SPOJ problem that I seem to have solved but when I run it an error SIGSEGV appears. Even though I read what this error is about (sort of referring to nonexistent elements of an array, if I got it right), I have trouble with finding my mistake in my [code](http://pastebin.com/YsLyVg5E).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;
int results[214];
void Solution(int number)   // The real part of the program
{
    int r,c;   // rows and columns
    char ch;
    int var;   // current input value of cell
    int a[101][101]={0};   // a[i][j] is the sum of cells from the top left element 1,1 to the one with indexes i,j
    int max=INT_MIN;   // here the max numbers of bananas is kept
    cin>>r>>c;
    for(int i=1;i<=r;i++)
        for(int k=1;k<=c;k++)
            {
                cin>>ch;
                switch (ch)   // Transforms chars to numbers
                {
                    case 'B': var=1; break;
                    case 'T': var=-1; break;
                    default: var=0;
                }
                a[i][k]=a[i][k-1]+a[i-1][k]-a[i-1][k-1]+var;
            }
    int maxSide=r; 
    if(c<r) maxSide=c;   // just checking the smaller side
    for(int i=1;i<=maxSide;i++)   // The various lengths of the square area that is long i cells and
        for(int p=1;p<=r-i+1;p++)   // the top left corner has indexes p and q
            for(int q=1;q<=c-i+1;q++)
            {
                int x;   // current number of bananas
                x=a[p+r-1][q+r-1]-a[p-1][q+r-1]-a[p+r-1][q-1]+a[p-1][q-1];
                if(x>max) max=x;   // comparing if this is the maximum amount of bananas so far
            }
    results[number]=max;   // puts the max number of bananas for each case
}
int main()
{
    int T;   // number of cases
    cin>>T; 
    for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
        Solution(i); 
    for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
        cout<<"Case "<<i<<": "<<results[i]<<endl;   //outputs all the result of each case
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what input are you giving to the program?

Comment: the tests given in the problem page plus a few simple ones made by hand on the course of writing, nothing too fancy, but the problem isn't too hard to need any special test cases (is it?)

Comment: can you provide here one of the inputs that causes a crash?

Comment: The thing is that I never personally had errors. As I submit it as a solution to the [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MONKK/) it returns sigsegv error. And I doubt that they have something wrong because quite some people have already solved it .

Comment: @RobertoAttias I found a mistake. The formula should be `x=a[p+i-1][q+i-1]-a[p-1][q+i-1]-a[p+i-1][q-1]+a[p-1][q-1];` However, even though it still gives true answers in the test cases given, the general report when the code is submitted is "wrong answer". Quite discouraging. At least the SIGSEGV error is gone.

Comment: As a general rule, `valgrind` on Linux is a very useful tool for diagnosing SIGSEGV errors in your code.